# How to combine mouse and event handlers together in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx-2

I'm creating this typical graphs software where on each click you add a node, on <kbd>Shift</kbd>+Click on nodes you draw a vertex, etc. So I want to create some Mouse-Key combinations for triggering algorithms. For example, an Alt+K+Click event turns into the Kruskal graph ....

So far I've done:

```
root.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
        if (t.isAltDown()) {

            root.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(KeyEvent k) {
                       System.out.println(k.getText());
        }
.....
.....
}
```

I got to a "scanning" buffer of keys but I don't know how to stop it, k.consume isn't working ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the action that you want to perform as an ActionListener to a MenuItem, you can use the MenuItem accelerator property to specify a key combination that will trigger it.  Some good examples at: http://thierrywasyl.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/keyboard-shortcuts-and-mnemonic-in-javafx/